# Hide Site ID from invoices

Tags: cartthrob

Since upgrading to CT2.5 I have started to get a Site ID value output with my order items tag in my invoice template. Is there a way to hide this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using an `{item_options}` tag pair within your `{exp:cartthrob:order_items}` tags in your invoice template. Something like:

```
{item_options}
    {option_name}: {option_value}
{/item_options}
```

Add a conditional to check for a "Site Id" `{option_label}` and only show the non Site Id options.

```
{item_options}
    {if option_label != "Site Id"}{option_name}: {option_value}{/if}
{/item_options}
```